# Adding a whitespace in front of the first number in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a whitespace to be added in front of the first number of a string, unless there is one already and unless the number is the first character in the string.

So I wrote this JS code:

```
document.getElementById('billing:street1').addEventListener('blur', function() {

  var value = document.getElementById('billing:street1').value;
  var array = value.match(/\d{1,}/g);

  if (array !== null) {
    var number = array[0];
    var index = value.indexOf(number);
        if(index !== 0){
        var street = value.substring(0, index);
            var housenumber = value.substring(index);
            if (street[street.length - 1] !== ' ') {
              document.getElementById('billing:street1').value = street + ' ' + housenumber;
             }
          }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/8/) 
It works fine, but I feel like this can probably be done in a smarter, more compact way.

Also, JQuery suggestions welcome, I am just not very familiar with it.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle your code is not clearing the concept here

Comment: There _is_ a jsfiddle link...

Comment: what i understand is if i write 1abcd then it should insert like 1 abcd like that ??

Comment: No, only **before** the number

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```js
const addSpace = (str) => {
   return str.replace(/(\D)(\d)/, "$1 $2") 
}
    
console.log(addSpace("12345"))     // "12345"
console.log(addSpace("city12345")) // "city 12345"
console.log(addSpace("city"))    // "city"
```

`(\D)` captures a non-digit

`(\d)` captures a digit

so `(\D)(\d)` means : non-digit followed by a digit

that we replace with `"$1 $2"` = captured1 + space + captured2

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for, except it will also add a whitespace before the second number in a scenario like: `34dfdf34` => `34dfdf 34`...

Comment: Only the first number should be affected and only in cases when it is not the first in the string or if there is a whitespace in front already

Comment: Ah, that complicates things. We need Lookbehind, but apparently it's not supported by JS regex engines

Comment: I am working with a `.phtml` file, so I could technically do the regex through PHP I guess

Comment: it is the house number causing the problem and address conventions are very confusing in some countries so I want to make the field as versatile as I can

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using only regular expressions. For example:

```
var s = "abcde45";

if(!s.match(/\s\d/)){

  s = s.replace(/(\d)/, ' $1');  

}
console.log(s); // "abcde 45"
```

**UPD :** Of course, if you have string with a wrong syntax(e.g no numbers inside), that code wouldn't work.

Comment: This will add a whitespace if the number is the first character in the string, which I mentioned I don't want